# Bigger icons when cycling windows in Xfce

Tags: linux, xfce, window-manager, icons, xfwm4

[image]

Disabling previews under "Compositor" in Window Manager Tweaks shows icons while cycling windows. But these are smaller than the previews. I would like to have them larger.

[image]

Something like those in Whisker Menu when set to "Large"

[image]

[image]

Can this be "tweaked" somehow for xfwm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Add the following to ~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css:

```
#xfwm-tabwin {
-XfwmTabwinWidget-icon-size: 256;
-XfwmTabwinWidget-preview-size: 256; }
```

icon-size changes the size of the icon and preview-size the size of the preview window. Adjust the values to suit, but I believe 256 is the largest size but depending on monitor size, it might go to 512.

Comment: 128 is already too big. 64 is big enough, as big as with "large" setting for  the menu